Ways to define real multiplication and addition
The discussion below is mostly targeted towards teaching math to first semesters of an abstract mathematical major.
I feel like teaching addition and multiplication in the usual way feels unsatisfactory to students and definitely has been unsatisfactory to me when I first learned it. Let me try to explain what I mean by this:
Most courses start by defining the natural numbers by using Peano axioms and introducing a successor function $S: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}, n \mapsto n+1$. Then the addition of two natural numbers is defined recursively by:
\begin{align} 
a + 0 &= a \\
a + S(b) &= S(a+b) 
\end{align}
In my experience once a student has understood how a function really works, the above definition is understood very easily for most students since it is closely linked to the enumerating property of natural numbers they are used to.
Obviously multiplication can now be defined intuitively by repeated addition.
If now the integers and rational numbers are defined as solutions to the equations $$n + x = m \, \, \,  n,m \in \mathbb{N}$$ and
$$qx = p \, \, \, p,q \in \mathbb{Z}, q \neq 0 $$
respectively, addition and multiplication are also defined in an at least intuitively very clear way. Seeing as the negative integers have a 1:1 correspondence to the positive natural numbers, addition and multiplication can be defined piecewise using this bijection. Then the addition of two rational numbers can be explained by integer addition, multiplication and forming inverses:
$$\frac{p_1}{q_1} + \frac{p_2}{q_2} = \frac{p_1q_2 + p_2q_1}{q_1q_2}$$
Now I think we come towards a crossroads. Depending on the construction of the real numbers used, the answer to what real addition and multiplication is can differ drastically. For example, defining real numbers as the closure of the rationals by using Cauchy sequences is at least in my experience the definition which is the best understood for students. Then for example when asked "Give meaning to the term $\pi + e$", most students define rational Cauchy sequences and use limit theorems to explain:
\begin{align}
\pi + e = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n + \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_n = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (a_n + b_n)
\end{align}
which is obviously completely true and very close to the way the reals are constructed in the first place. But then the answer to "How do I add two irrational numbers?" is just answered by "Well, I understand rational addition and the sum of two irrational numbers is the limit of some sequences". But does that really answer that question? I feel like it just relocates the problem to the point of infinity which we can not possibly grasp fully. And also the idea of multiplication just being repeated addition completely fades away.
So my main question is: What are other ways to define real addition and multiplication other than Cauchy-Sequences? Can any of them explain the question of how to add irrational numbers in a more satisfying way to a undergrad? Or given the way real numbers are constructed - in this case as the closure of the rationals -  we can not give a better answer to this question as we are being hindered by the construction itself?
Feel free to include math which is generally not considered suited to first semesters (like the construction of the reals from surreal numbers if the answer is somewhat "nicer" in this case).

You can use dedekind cuts. Then you're just adding sets of rational numbers to other sets of rational numbers.
